# show the menu only when user hovers on it for 3 sec

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

i want show and hide the div's when the user hover the menu this should happen only when the user hover on it for 2 secs

my code here

```
 $(".listing-menu li a").hover(function () {
                $(".listing-menu li a").removeClass('selected');       
                $("#divhouses,#divplots,#divproperties,#divapartment,#divprojects,#divbuilders").addClass("hide");
                var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("tab", "div"); $("#" + id).removeClass("hide");$(this).addClass('selected');
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use SetTimeout in jquery.

```
setTimeout ( function() {

        // here call hover function
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a timer like

```
$(".listing-menu li a").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".listing-menu li a").removeClass('selected');
        $("#divhouses,#divplots,#divproperties,#divapartment,#divprojects,#divbuilders").addClass("hide");
        var id = $this.attr('id').replace("tab", "div");
        $("#" + id).removeClass("hide");
        $this.addClass('selected');
    }, 2000);
    $this.data('hoverTimer', timer)
}, function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
});
```